# ConfidentialStore error on distributed Jenkins plugin running on slave

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, distributed

I'm refactoring (not by choice) a Jenkins plugin (that I didn't write) so it can run distributed. The plugin is simple, it basically takes the resulting object from the job, creates a changelog, compresses them both in a zip file and sends it through an http post request to an app.

Following http://ccoetech.ebay.com/tutorial-dev-jenkins-plugin-distributed-jenkins I moved the code that's going to run on the node to a class like this:

```java
private static class UploadLauncher implements Callable <Void, Exception> {
  ...
  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception {
     // Here's the code to run in the node.
     ...
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that somewhere in the code the plugin tries to configure the proxy like this:

```java
ProxyConfiguration proxy;
if (Jenkins.getInstance() != null && Jenkins.getInstance().proxy != null) {
  proxy = Jenkins.getInstance().proxy;
} else {
  proxy = new ProxyConfiguration("", 0, "", "");
}

//Continue proxy configuration code
```

Because I'm doing this on my local machine and I don't have a proxy configured (I actually don't know if the production server uses one) the code always goes through the else statement, and it's failing throwing an exception on this instruction `proxy = new ProxyConfiguration("", 0, "", "");`

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot initialize confidential key store until Jenkins has started
at jenkins.security.ConfidentialStore.get(ConfidentialStore.java:68)
at jenkins.security.ConfidentialKey.load(ConfidentialKey.java:47)
at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.getKey(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:32)
at jenkins.security.CryptoConfidentialKey.decrypt(CryptoConfidentialKey.java:67)
at hudson.util.Secret.decrypt(Secret.java:137)
at hudson.util.Secret.fromString(Secret.java:186)
at hudson.ProxyConfiguration.<init>(ProxyConfiguration.java:117)
at hudson.ProxyConfiguration.<init>(ProxyConfiguration.java:109)
at hudson.ProxyConfiguration.<init>(ProxyConfiguration.java:105)
at example.maduploader.MADRecorder$UploadLauncher.getHttpClient(MADRecorder.java:363)
```

This happens only when the plugin runs on the slave node, if the job executes on the master node the plugin works fine.

Also I'm a python programmer I've only done things in Java back at college so maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way.